# Passing a file to jqGrid controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails, jqgrid

I'm using Grails and jqGrid and am trying to get a rather strange extension working:
I want to let the user upload a file that will be passed to the jqGrid controller and used to filter the data.  For example the file is a list of names and the grid will be filtered to rows containing those names.  Is there any simple way to do this?

What I have been trying is to use AJAX fileuploader with a FormData object and trying to attach it to the jqGrid params.  The closest I have gotten is to use the following, though I am getting some weird behavior:

```
<g:form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload" name="fileinfo" id="fileinfo">
    <input name="uploadField" id="uploadField" type="file" value="">
    <input id="btnFilterFile" type="button" onclick="addFileFilter()" value="Apply Filter"/>
</g:form>

<table id="theGrid"></table>

<script>
function addFileFilter() {
    var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo"));
    $("#theGrid").setGridParam({ajaxGridOptions: 
        {processData:false, type:'POST', data:oData}});

    $("#theGrid").trigger("reloadGrid");
 }
 </script>
```

This is the only way I have been able to get the file data to reach the controller, but it seems to overwrite all my other search/sort/paging parameters from the grid.  If I define the "data" ajax parameter is a key:object pair, then the grid simply won't reload and it won't even give me an error!  If anyone has any advice on this, I would really appreciate it!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up finding a rather strange work-around for this that solves the issue, though is probably not the best style:

The biggest issue was that passing a FormData object (file) from view to controller requires that the "processingData" attribute of the AJAX call be false.  I could not get this working within jqGrid itself so I made a separate AJAX call that sends the FormData object to the controller and saves it in a global variable (bad style!).  Another option would be to save it in the domain, but the global variable is fine for me.  My controller action then just uses the global variable for filtering.  I just had to make sure I clear the global variable when first visiting the page (with another ajax call).

Here is a code sample from the view:

```
<style>
function clearFileField() {
    $("#uploadField").val("");
    var url="${createLink(controller:"${pageType}",action:'clearFileFilter')}";
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        type:'POST',
        success: function(data) {
            $("${gridId}").trigger("reloadGrid");
        }
    });
}

function addFileFilter() {
    var oData = new FormData(document.forms.namedItem("fileinfo"));
    var url="${createLink(controller:"${pageType}",action:'saveFileFilter')}";
    jQuery.ajax({
        async: false,
        url: url,
        type:'POST',
        data: oData,
        processData:false,
        contentType: false
    });
    $("${gridId}").trigger("reloadGrid");
}

$( "#btnFilterByHostFile" ).click(function() {
    addFileFilter();
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    clearFileField();
}
</script>

<g:form enctype="multipart/form-data" class="upload" name="fileinfo" id="fileinfo">
    <input name="uploadField" id="uploadField" type="file" value="">
</g:form>
```

And here are the controller actions:

```
def static List<String> filterList = new ArrayList()

def saveFileFilter = {
    InputStream is = params.uploadField?.getInputStream()
    def fileString = is.readLines()
    is.close()

    filterList = fileString
    def response = [state: "OK", id: 1]
    render response as JSON
}

def clearFileFilter = {
    filterList = []
    def response = [state: "OK", id: 1]
    render response as JSON
}
```

Then in the controller action for the jqGrid, I can just use "filterList" as part of the query.